# Modify FTP to add session recovery

Tags: ftp

I want to modify FTP so that it recovers from the last session during file transfer and during next time it should start from the point where the connection was lost.

Is it possible to do this ? where to start from to achieve this ?
It is already implemented in FTP ? or any other similar protocols which i can refer ?
Source code would be fine  in case it is already implemented.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it yourself,

C#: http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_network/sockets/article.php/c7409/A-C-FTP-Server.htm

C/C++: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2558/A-Complete-FTP-Server

Python: http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/examples/#auto8

**EDIT**

you have the command `REST` with which you can specify the where to start from